# Can I dynamically output a list of 3 recent posts into default text in Wordpress editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I was hoping someone could help me learn how to achieve this.

My idea is to generate a list of 3 recent posts from a category (top posts) as a default text in the wordpress editor.

I looked at several solutions to achieve something similar and kind of mixed them into the code below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
add_filter('default_content', 'tp4567_default_list');
function tp4567_default_list( $content ) {
$content = new WP_Query( 'cat=2&posts_per_page=3' );
return $content;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in functions.php, it will work.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wp_my_default_content', 10, 2 );
function wp_my_default_content( $content, $post ) 
{
// get the posts
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts'   => 3
    )
);

// No posts? run away!
if( empty( $posts ) ) return '';

$content = '<ul>';
foreach( $posts as $post )
{
    $content .= sprintf( 
        '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
        get_permalink( $post ),
        esc_attr( $post->post_title ),
        esc_html( $post->post_title )
    );
}
$content .= '</ul>';
return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That does the trick. I just added the category needed in the get_posts(array) to match my need. 

I added this as a plugin to my site, but somehow it gave me an error at the first attempt. So I changed the name of the function from "wp_my_default_content" to something else and it all works great now. Many thanks again! :)